# How to Display incorrect password error in html page without using javascript

Tags: java, servlets, html

I want to display the Password wrong error in html page , i can do it in different page by using requestdispatcher but how to display it in same login page using only java and html , i dont have any idea about javascript , thank you

HTML Code :

```
<p>Sign into your account</p>
<form action="bs" align="center" method="POST" onSubmit="return 
validateLogin()">
<input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Username"><br>
<input type="password" name="pswd2" placeholder="Password"><br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login!" >
<span style="color:red;">${errMsg)</span>
</form>
```

Servlet Code :

```
 if(rs.next())
    {
        ResultSet rs1=stmt.executeQuery(vsql1);

        if(rs1.next())
        {
            out.println("----Welcome----");
        }
        else
        {
             request.setAttribute("errMsg", "Invalid username or password"); 
              RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
              dispatcher.forward( request, response);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        request.setAttribute("errMsg", "Invalid username or password"); 
              RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
              dispatcher.forward( request, response);
    }

    }
```

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: if you want to display the error message in the same page, you will have to use javascript. Or if you have a JSP, you can use JSTL/EL.

Comment: how to display using java script

Answer (score 0):

PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter();
out.println("Password mismatch);

It will display this value in browser

Comment: yh , but it wont display in the same page . i want the error to be displayed in the same login page so user can enter password again

Comment: You can use sessionAttribute. request.getSession().setAttribute("errorMessage", "Invalid password");